# How can I get the carousel to work in landing_page.html.erb without changing the products index view?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap, e-commerce, carousel

I'm trying to pull the first three or four products from the database and display them as the individual slides, with all the content (image, name, description, link) populated dynamically. So if the products ever get updated, the new ones will appear on the homepage without needing to modify any code. I'm getting the error in the screen shot attached. All I changed was the landing_page.html.erb which is at https://gist.github.com/Faisal-Hassan/fc0f19c6efe3fe8756d4 and the products controller at https://gist.github.com/Faisal-Hassan/828793f22ebb88fcbcc6. The products index and the rest of the unchanged files are over at https://github.com/Faisal-Hassan/vzncommerce .

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have your controllers messed up. The page you are using (`landing_page`) is under the `Static Pages` controller. Therefore, your code that loads the `@products` object should be in your `Static Pages` controller, not in your `Products` controller.

In your `Static Pages` controller, the `landing_page` code should look like this:

```
class StaticPagesController < ApplicationController
  def landing_page
    @products = Product.limit(3)
  end
end
```

Comment: The error is gone but the products are still not showing up in the carousel.